# Electric water heater grounding wire not connected

Tags: electrical, water-heater, grounding

While replacing an element in my electric water heater, I noticed this wire, which is attached to the shell of the water heater, is just sitting in the lower element area, without being attached to anything. Should it be attached? What should I attach it to?

[image]

Comment: The grounding wire (green/yellow) is attached. The red wire is of unknown function aand you have failed to specify EXACTLY what electric water heater you have so it's function is unknowable. But it ain't ground.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  The grounding wire is attached, but with all the corrosion I doubt it is still making a connection.

Comment: Definitely need to know brand/model to look up the schematics to see where that wire is supposed to be attached.